# Variable JSON structure mapping with Go struct type

Tags: json, go

I have a JSON that is as follows

```
{
  "Key1": "Value1",
  "Key2": "Value2",
  "Key3": {
    "InnerKey1": "InnerValue1",
    "InnerKey2": "InnerValue2",
    ...
  }
}
```

The problem I have is with the Key3 structure which contains a key value of variable length. It is possible that the client sends me another key. How do I create a `struct` for this in Go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [json2go](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/). For the variable part you could use a map

And you get:

```
type AutoGenerated struct {
    Key1 string `json:"Key1"`
    Key2 string `json:"Key2"`
    Key3 map[string]string `json:"Key3"`
}
```